# How can I contribute to the LibreOffice dictionary?

Tags: libreoffice, dictionary, spell-checking, contributing

I always add words to my LibreOffice dictionary (standard.dic), but I would love to make those words available to other users by contributing to the project's dictionaries.
Is there a way LibreOffice can produce statistics about how often a word is added in dictionaries from users wishing to help? Or is there a project I can join to participate in the dictionaries editing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libreoffice is not developed by the Ubuntu development community. This is the place to go if you wish to get involved in the development of Libreoffice:

[Get involved in Libreoffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/get-involved/)

Also Libreoffice uses [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) as the spell-checker. You need to research how Hunspell creates dictionaries.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The user dictionary is just for personal use. LibreOffice does not actually collect words for dictionaries, instead it just assembles existing ones. I think the best way for personal contributions is through [Wiktionary](http://wiktionary.org) from which maybe in the future additional dictionaries can be built.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add words to a dictionary, is to contact the author of the dictionary.

Check this site to see how: [Dictionaries in LibreOffice](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Dictionaries).